# What would cause the use of LB_GETITEMRECT to only return the top and bottom dimensions of an item?

Tags: c++, winapi, listbox

As I was trying to figure out how to determine the appropriate horizontal scrolling extent of a Listbox common control in Win32 API, ultimately I was satisfied to adapt the code from [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13679277/listbox-change-width-dynamically/13679739#13679739).

However, I still have a curiosity that won't go away as to why my initial technique didn't work. I was trying to use LB_GETITEMRECT, as I assumed that the Listbox knew the dimensions of each item because, after all, it had to render their text. It seemed a reasonable assumption to me that this information would be known to the control.

Here is a distillation of my initial attempt:

```cpp
void
SetMaxListBoxExtent(HWND const p_listbox)
{
    int const item_count = SendMessage
    (
        p_listbox,
        LB_GETCOUNT,
        (WPARAM) 0,
        (LPARAM) 0
    );

    int max_item_width = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < item_count, i += 1)
    {
        RECT item_rect = { 0 };

        // (i indexes the items in the ListBox).
        SendMessage
        (
            p_listbox,
            LB_GETITEMRECT,
            i,
            (LPARAM) &item_rect
        );

        int const item_width = (item_rect.right - item_rect.left);

        if(item_width > max_item_width)
            max_item_width = item_width;
    )

    // I would set horizontal extent of the Listbox here using max_item_width,
    // but this series of operations results in zero extent, so it's useless. 
    // Why is it behaving this way?
}
```

When I went to run this code, I found that the `top` and `bottom` members of `item_rect` seemed to be properly set, but `left` and `right` were always zero. Now, it's not totally surprising to me that `left` would be zero, but why should `right`? Is this message implicitly only intended for multicolumn listboxes? I couldn't find anything to indicate this in the searches I've attempted.

Comment: `LB_GETITEMRECT` return correct rect size including `right`. may be your `p_listbox` have 0 horizontal size when you call `LB_GETITEMRECT`. if you call `GetClientRect(p_listbox, &item_rect);` - what will be result ?

Comment: This question can't be answered without seeing a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding. I figured it out, I was silly. I was so sure that this window was visible, but it wasn't. That said, it is odd that it returns something for `top` and `bottom`. It returns a slice of the client area of the Listbox, as @RbMm surmised. (`GetClientRect` returns a `RECT` of all zeroes.)

What's strange is that when the Listbox is visible, this works even for items that aren't currently visible to the user. Either way, it wouldn't have given me what I was looking for anyway. The `right` boundary returned is the righthand boundary of the Listbox itself.